# SQL Server 'Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date' error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanted to create a membership limit to the database. For this, I added using the ALTER command. Then I wanted to return the number of months remaining until the end of membership with a function, but I got the error

> Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date.

I am getting the error while trying to create the function. This is exactly how it is:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure getMembershipExpiration, Line 1
> Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

```
ALTER TABLE Member
ADD Membership_End_Date DATE DEFAULT '2099-01-01' not null

CREATE FUNCTION getMembershipExpiration(@Member_ID int)
RETURNS date
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @endDate date = (SELECT Membership_End_Date FROM Member WHERE Member_ID =@Member_ID)
    
    DECLARE @nnow date = (SELECT GETDATE())
    
    DECLARE @remainingMonth date = (SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH,@nnow ,@endDate ))
    
    RETURN @remainingMonth
END
```

As a solution, it was suggested to put the date part in quotation marks and write it in the YYYY-MM-DD pattern, but it did not lead me to the solution.

Comment: change function to: RETURN int instead of date and @remainingMonth to type int

Comment: and please also declare  @remainingMonth int

Comment: Do you really need a function for this? SQL isn't a programming language, putting logic like this into a (likely) non-inlined scalar function will only hinder performance.

Comment: Perhaps adding a computed column would be a better idea.

Comment: @Larnu Our lecturer at the university gave it as homework, there is nothing to do :).

Comment: I *hope* your lecturer taught you the above too then.

Comment: @Stu I think it would make more sense to call it as a function whenever the user wants it. Every day calculation of the database would be reflected as unnecessary workload.

Comment: @TalhaBurakAydın unfortunately you "think" wrong. A scalar function, especially if you're using 2017 or prior, would certainly perform worse than a computed column.

Comment: @Larnu Theoretically they taught but in practice they do the trick a bit.

Comment: As evidence of how slow, comparatively, a scalar function is, note that the computed column and expression in the `SELECT` took 0ms, the `FUNCTION`, however, took over 800ms on SQL Server 2017: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/w85OAxom) If you don't have a covering index, it gets even worse: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rmvL0EtQ) This is true on 2022 too, [1](https://dbfiddle.uk/YuHlMhwG), [2](https://dbfiddle.uk/rRtxjyrF)

Comment: Going back to your error, your function returns the number of months between 2 dates, which is an int, but you declare your function saying you return a date. You need to sort out what your function should be returning and keep it consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DATEDIFF` returns `int`, not `date`. Replace line #5 with:

```
RETURNS int
```

and line #12 with:

```
DECLARE @remainingMonth int = (SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH,@nnow ,@endDate ))
```